# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c program

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

i am using gcc compiler on ubuntu 14.04 LTS for compilation of following c program

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int *a,*b;
        *a=2;
        *b=3;
          printf("\n printing address.....\n address of a = %d \n address of b = %d \n",a,b);
         printf("\n\n printing values ..... \n value of a = %d \n value of b = %d \n",*a,*b);
      }
```

and when i run above program than i get following in output

```
      output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

please suggest where i am doing wrong. 

thanks

Comment: `int A,B;int *a=&A, *b=&B;`

Comment: `void main` is wrong, btw. `main` returns `int`.

Comment: **Always** compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Weror`. This will prevent you from making such stupid mistakes.

Comment: Also time to learn how to use gdb.... `gdb ./mypgram`, and `r`.

Comment: You can't just assign arbitrary values to *pointers*.  I think you want to define integers and then reference their address with `&a` and `&b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're declaring and using pointers (pointed-to memory), without allocating space for them.

Just declaring:

```
int *a;
```

doesn't give you memory to use, this just declares a variable that can reference memory.

The pointer, once declared, is *un-initialized*, and will point to some part of memory that doesn't belong to you. Using that memory - in your case, putting a value there - will result in undefined behavior; you see a core dump when you touch that memory.

In order to get some space to use, learn about `malloc`:

```
int *a = NULL;   // good practive to initialize/reset pointers to NULL

// malloc will give you space for 1 int, and a will point to that new space
a = malloc(sizeof(int));

if (a != NULL)   // malloc returns NULL in the event of a failure
{
    // a is non-NULL so now we can use the memory pointed-to:
    *a = 5;

    // other code that uses a goes here:
    ...


    // and when you're finished with a give the memory back:
    free(a);
    a = NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you ask this question, this means you really need to learn C (course or book) or switch to another language

Comment: The answer above is completely correct. Or he can learn the hard way :-) Asking questions and googling and hitting errors. Takes longer, but it gets you there, or makes you want to read more.

Comment: The *reason* it's a good to set pointer a to NULL is not clear from the example. You don't want to risk `a` being randomly initialized to a bogus value, and try to free or access it.  It is harmless to free() NULL, but a serious bug to free a non-legitimate address value.  For that reason, best practice is to set a pointer to NULL after free memory at the address pointed to, so there's no attempt to access freed memory later (which can cause a crash).  By handling pointers that way you can always know a pointer refers to valid memory or not by comparing it to NULL. Will save you many headaches

Comment: @nerdistcolony thought that might be too much detail in this case but I've amended the code sample with more that might be useful for a beginner

Comment: I wasn't berating your post in any way, merely amending it. Your update to it is good.

Comment: Defining `int *p` does, in fact, create space for the pointer... It just doesn't allocate any space for you to store actual values into.  What you have is a handle without a shovel.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a pointer

```
int* p;
```

it is similar as declaring an integer variable:

```
int v;
```

the contents of `v` is uninitialized - same with `p` - it is also uninitialized so when you use `p` e.g. `*p` you may be dereferencing an address anywhere in memory, even in read-only memory. Instead you need to initialize the variables.

```
int v = 0;
int* p = &v;  // p points to v in memory
```